# Phd without stipend fees

Tags: phd

Hi guys im a domestic university  student  in Australia that just finished a masters in biotechnology and bioinformatics. I had one year of coursework with my final year being a practical year in which I had a year to write my thesis. By the end of my degree, I had found a supervisor at Monash Uni that had agreed to take me on. I have read on the Monash entry requirements for a Phd in science is a minimum H2A in which I achieved but i am still worried i could get rejected by my supervisor. However, I don't think i will be high enough to get the scholarship.

Is the scholarship necessary to pursue the Phd or not? I live at home with my parents so I don't have anything to worry about financially but do I need the scholarship for the fees or not.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This depends on how expensive the fees are and on how much you can afford to spend. These are unknown variables for us.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot tell you whether you can sustain yourself for the duration of a PhD. We cannot tell you whether you parents will continue to house, feed, cloth, etc., during your PhD either. Whether you need a scholarship to pay fees is also something we cannot tell you.

Previous questions and answers may help guide you towards a decision. Please consider the following: https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=self+funded+phd

---

<sup>I have assumed *scholarship* includes *stipend*, in the context of the OP's question.</sup>

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, yes i live with my parents at the moment and will probably continue to do so during my phd. I think my main concern would be the fees that i would need to pay.

Comment: @A.y Your specific situation isn't really something _people on the internet_ can help with. But, please do consider other questions and answers, I really do think they'll help guide you, perhaps towards a more specific question. (I haven't voted to close this question, but others have, since _The answer to this question strongly depends on individual factors such as a certain person’s preferences, a given institution’s regulations, the exact contents of your work or your personal values. Thus only someone familiar can answer this question and it cannot be generalised to apply to others._)